# how to trigger a function when the keyboard is exited on a mobile device react web app

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to trigger a function when the user exits the keyboard or clicks "done" in the top left corner of the keyboard on an ios device within a react application created with create-react-app

Comment: Doesn't that fire the `blur` event?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.